NamingException: OracleDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.OracleDS
This is my java code for connection manager..

public static synchronized Connection getSISConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        Context ctx;
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            System.out.println("Initializing connection0000...");

            // Set the context factory for WildFly
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
            System.out.println("INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY set.");

            // Set the provider URL for remote JNDI access
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080"); // Ensure this is the correct port for JNDI access--  remote://127.0.0.1:4447
            System.out.println("PROVIDER_URL set.");

            // Set security credentials
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin"); // Your JBoss username
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin@123"); // Your JBoss password

            // Create the initial context
            ctx = new InitialContext(props);

            // Perform the lookup for the datasource
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/OracleDS"); // Ensure this JNDI name is correct
            if (ds != null) {
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                System.out.println("Connection established successfully.");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Datasource lookup failed.");
            }
            return conn;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.err.println("NamingException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


We are using Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.3 server
error
17:23:03,079 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Initializing connection0000...
17:23:03,079 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY set.
17:23:03,079 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) PROVIDER_URL set.
17:23:03,084 INFO  [org.wildfly.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WildFly Naming version 1.0.11.Final-redhat-00001
17:23:03,366 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) NamingException: OracleDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.OracleDS
17:23:03,367 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: OracleDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.OracleDS
17:23:03,367 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.as.naming@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
17:23:03,367 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.as.naming@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
17:23:03,367 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.as.naming@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
17:23:03,367 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.as.naming@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
17:23:03,367 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.naming-client@1.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport.handleLookup(RemoteServerTransport.java:200)
17:23:03,367 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.naming-client@1.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport$1.handleMessage(RemoteServerTransport.java:120)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.16.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$receiveMessage$2(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:361)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.16.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
17:23:03,368 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "conn" is null
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at deployment.viewControllerApp.war//ei.integration.scheduler.ServletStartBean.init(ServletStartBean.java:25)
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
17:23:03,369 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
17:23:03,370 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
17:23:03,371 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
17:23:03,371 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
How it will be resolve the error ?

Have you created a datasource with that name in the wildfly console?

yes I created the same datasource in JBoss server console
